# expectation and power of n

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let X be a random variable such that $X\geq 0$ with $E[X^n] = \infty$. We must prove that $E[X^m] = \infty$ for every $m\geq n$.

Comment: Try writing $E[X^n]=E[(X^m)^{n/m}]$ and then applying Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$$X^m\geqslant X^m\mathbf{1}_{X\geqslant 1}=X^{m-n}\mathbf{1}_{X\geqslant 1}X^n\geqslant X^n\mathbf{1}_{X\geqslant 1}$$

Comment: According to site regulations, answering questions without context and where the OP does not show any effort is not advised.